# Office 365 AD FS an error occurred

Tags: office365, adfs

Whenever I try and login with a synced ADFS user, I run into this error ([an error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUIKf.png)), and these entries show up under Server Manager > AD FS > Events:

```
Server Name   ID    Severity    Source    Log          Date and Time
T-ADFS-01     364   Error       AD FS     AD FS/Admin  4/12/2016 5:02:05 PM
T-ADFS-01     1000  Warning     AD FS     AD FS/Admin  4/12/2016 5:02:05 PM
T-ADFS-01     111   Error       AD FS     AD FS/Admin  4/12/2016 5:02:05 PM
T-ADFS-01     238   Error       AD FS     AD FS/Admin  4/12/2016 5:02:05 PM
```

I read several articles that recommended enabling Forms Authentication by:
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3015526)

1. In Server Manager on the AD FS 3.0 server, click **Tools**, and then select **AD FS Management**.
2. In the AD FS snap-in, click **Authentication Policies**.
3. In the **Primary Authentication** section, click **Edit** next to Global Settings.
4. In the **Edit Global Authentication Policy** dialog box, click the Primary tab, and then under **Extranet** and under **Intranet**, click to select the **Forms Authentication** check box.

But this didn't work. How do I go about diagnosing these error logs?

Comment: Look in Event Viewer under "Applications and Services" / AD FS / Admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having an issue like this, I would double check the administrator accounts logged in the **Active Directory Federation Services** service (Computer Management > Services) and the **Federation Service Account** used in configuring Azure AD. During our troubleshooting we noticed the accounts used for those were outside the local domain.

We uninstalled/reinstalled the AD FS server role and Azure AD, inputting proper *local* administrator accounts where required, which resolved the issue.